# How do I apply styling to polymer elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polymer-1.0

I've been trying to read the documentation, but I don't get it. There doesn't seem to be any stackoverflow questions too. Right now using Polymer v1.0 with MVC 5.

For example, let's take the paper-toolbar. I have this sample code:

```
<paper-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <span class="title">My Title</span>
    <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="add">+</paper-icon-button>
</paper-toolbar>
```

How do I apply a white background to it?

[In the polymer website:](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toolbar)

I've seen that there are custom properties and mixins... but how do I use them?

For example, how would I override the "--paper-toolbar-background"? to make the background white?

Thanks!

Comment: In this case you can just use pure CSS. Something like `paper-toolbar { background: #fff; }`

Comment: Isn't that covered in the [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toolbar?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-toolbar)?

Comment: I'm asking because I have a bootstrap mentality, in which we just decorate the element with classes instead of overriding it with our own code (unless we are heavily modifying it).

Comment: Like for example, if there was a class or a mixin that already has all the material colors outlined and we just need to name it.

Comment: Yup, found something like: var(--google-green-500); Where can I find other colors? Quick Google search does not output anything similar.

Comment: is the [paper-styles](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles) component what your looking for?

Comment: @2pha: Yeah :D Thanks! The color.html has all the properties I'm looking for :D!!! Woot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I recommend is having an element for styling purposes, for example an `app-theme.html`. Put it inside your elements directory and import it.

If your `app-theme.html` looks like the following, it should style your paper-toolbar properly:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-toolbar {
        --paper-toolbar-background: var(--paper-blue-900);
    }
</style>
```

I use this approach for the Paper elements. For custom elements I put the styling inside each element.

Though theoretically you could just take my above code and paste it just before you use the element, but this approach has the issue that the default styling is applied before, resulting in breaks.

Of course you could also just use a normal app.css file to style the paper elements, but then you would have to use the `!important` attribute to overwrite the default styling of the element. Don't recommend it though.

Hope it helps.

George